# Facebook ASP.NET Coding Problems (Trying to get the CodePlex examples to work)

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I'm trying to get the following code to work:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic  
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Facebook
Imports Facebook.WebControls

Public Partial Class _Default
    Inherits CanvasIFrameBasePage
    Private Const FACEBOOK_API_KEY As String = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    Private Const FACEBOOK_SECRET As String = "yyyyyyyyyy"

    Shadows Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.Api = FACEBOOK_API_KEY
        MyBase.Secret = FACEBOOK_SECRET
        MyBase.Page_Load(sender, e)

        If (Not IsPostBack) Then
            Try
                ' Use the FacebookService Component to populate Friends
                Dim u As Facebook.Entity.User = Me.FBService.GetUserInfo()

                Dim f As Collection(Of Facebook.Entity.User) = Me.FBService.GetFriends()


                Dim s As String = ""
                If f.Count <> 1 Then
                    s = "s"
                End If
                lblHelloWorld.Text = "Hello " & u.Name & " you have " & f.Count & " friend" & s & "..." & Me.FBService.SessionKey
                Me.FBService.SetFBML("Hello " & u.Name & " you have " & f.Count & " friend" & s)
            Catch e1 As Exception
                'Throw
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Requested value 'Networking' was not found.

failing on this line:

```
Dim u As Facebook.Entity.User = Me.FBService.GetUserInfo()
```

Can anyone help please?

It is called the Facebook Toolkit, located at http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: You might want to specify which facebook client API you're using from Codeplex.

Comment: Thanks Kurt...

it is The Facebook Toolkit located at http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/